# Mixed tense sentence + When clause

Tags: clauses, tenses, compound-sentences, when

Is it legal to write something like this:

> When I'm trying to post a form system alerts me with a warning message.

I've seen people use this kind of writing.

**EDIT**

I don't know why (perhaps that's the influence of my native languages and their semantical constructions) but my brain is considering such a form

> when I try to do something + present simple a.k.a something happens

I know that it would be just a description of usual activities like

> each time I ...

construction.

My activity I want to describe holds repetitive character: I do some routine jobs but in the perspective of **now**, and this may not happen in the future.

Sorry if this sounds confusing.

Comment: The simple answer to this question as is stands is "yes, it's legal". It would be a much better question if you could expand on what makes you think it might not be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The combination of tenses is fine as it is. The bigger problem is its lack of punctuation, which leads to confusion.

The when clause is your adverb clause. Placed at the beginning of a sentence, normally it should be separated from the independent clause by a comma:

> When S + V **,** S + V.

It's only when we place the adverb clause after the independent clause that we do away with the punctuation:

> S + V **when** S + V.

---

Now there are two ways to cut up the meaning chunks of your sentence:

> When I'm trying to post a form **,** system alerts me with a warning
>   message.

Or,

> When I'm trying to post **,** a form system alerts me with a warning
>   message.

For me, the first is more likely to work than the second. But more importantly, what has caused this ambiguity is: (1) the lack of a comma, and (2) the lack of an article.

If it were me, I'd place a definite article in front of "*system*" :

> When I'm trying to post a form, **the** system alerts me with a
>   warning message.

The version without an article can work in a more casual style of writing.

Comment: You have answered a question you wish he had asked, not the one he did ask.

Comment: Hi @RoaringFish. One, the title of the post is clear enough to me: "Mixed tense sentence." Two, RegDwight has already edited it. Three, the opportunity to teach the use of punctuation is too obvious to ignore. Four, I wish you'd place your downvotes according to the actual merit of the answer

Comment: Your answer (about punctuation) doesn't answer the question the OP asked (about tenses). As such it isn't actually an answer, hence has no actual merit as it fails as an answer, and hence deserves a downvote.

Comment: This is not the first time someone in EL&U has corrected something else extremely vital to the validity of a sentence in question. In any case, the OP has already submitted his query, I have already submitted my answer, and I'll just wait and see how the others would judge it. Thanks for letting me know your personal reasons and I'd prefer not to extend this thread of comments

Comment: RegDwight's edit made no substantial changes (merely changing the style for the quote). The OP's edit was forty minutes after your answer, although I'm not sure it's actually clarified anything.

Comment: Hi Andrew. Yeah, the OP's confused about the temporal correspondence in combining the Present Continuous and Present Simple in his particular example. I actually have an elaborate answer to that as well, but there isn't enough space. And I judge the problem of punctuation as being more pressing. Perhaps someone else would post an answer

Comment: @RoaringFish: But Cool Elf *does* answer the question, which is "Is it legal?"  The first thing Cool Elf says is "The combination of tenses is just fine".

Comment: @StoneyB ~ and that is where he should have stopped, in a comment. If the OP wanted to know about punctuation, he would have asked about punctuation. Say you booked a lesson about tenses, and the teacher spoke 9 words on tenses and then proceeded to lecture you on punctuation, would you be happy with that lesson, that didn't give you what you wanted? I wouldn't - I would think him a lousy teacher who was ignoring my concerns. "Answer what the student asks, not what you think they should ask" is one of the first things you learn in teacher training.

Comment: @RoaringFish, you sound like someone going to great lengths to discredit my answer

Comment: All I am doing is pointing out that you have answered your own question, not the OPs. If that is discrediting your answer, then it is your answer that discredits your answer. I can see you are touchy about that, so learn from it and make sure your future answers actually answer what the OP asks.

Comment: Very well. Like I said, I already accepted your opinion on the matter. Let's leave this discussion at that and just let other people judge for themselves.

Comment: Whole debate! Anyway the form of my question is obviously confusing and not quite clear. Sorry for that, guys. But anyway I have figure it out! Thank you for sharing your opinions.